# Build.json Error: Package application for Android

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Using Visual Studio RTM 2015 Blank Cordova (5.1.1) TypeScript project to test packaging applications for Android.

Following these instructions: https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/tree/master/tutorial-package-publish#android
Created the build.json and keystore.

When I publish (Release > Android > Device), I get the following error:
[image]

`Reading build config file: D:\erase\BlankCordovaApp9\build.json
Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "D:\erase\BlankCordovaApp9\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug --buildConfig=D:\erase\BlankCordovaApp9\build.json"
ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1`

Are the instructions still accurate for 2015 RTM?  Using the instructions I get `Misssing a comma after an object member` when using the suggested format in  build.json.

Win 8.1

Comment: Try adding comma after the entries in the json file to see if that fixes the issue, Thanks

Comment: Yes, the comma's are missing in the documentation.  My build.json includes the comma's.  Without the comma's, I get intellisense warnings so it's an easy fix.

Comment: Here my build.json minus password, etc. ---  `{
  "android": {
    "release": {
      "keystore": "D:\\\\folder\\folder\\androidrk.keystore",
      "storePassword": "xxx",
      "alias": "myName",
      "password": "xxx",
      "keystoreType": ""
    }
  }
}`

Comment: There seems to be a problem with Cordova 5.1.1 handling absolute paths to the keystore.  I can use relative paths, but not absolute.  
  
A bug was submitted to cordova-android about this issue.  Here's the link: [https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-android/commit/d3245a43d303b570daed1c2fc828deccbe306441](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-android/commit/d3245a43d303b570daed1c2fc828deccbe306441)